# Python: Increment pointer/view to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

If I was writing C++ I could do the following:

```
double foo [9] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}; 
double* bar = foo;
cout << bar[0] << ", " << bar[1] << ", " << bar[2] << "\n";
bar += 3;
cout << bar[0] << ", " << bar[1] << ", " << bar[2] << "\n";
bar += 3;
cout << bar[0] << ", " << bar[1] << ", " << bar[2] << "\n";
```

This would print:

```
0, 1, 2
3, 4, 5
6, 7, 8
```

I now want to do the same in numpy:

```
foo = np.arange((9))
bar = foo[:3]
print(bar)
???
print(bar)
???
print(bar)
```

But I don't know what to put at the `???` The result would hopefully be:

```
[0 1 2]
[3 4 5]
[6 7 8]
```

In other words, I'm looking for a way to change where the view `bar` is pointing at `foo`, using the existing reference `bar`.

That is I would like to be able to write the `???` as `bar = f(bar)`, where `f` is some function defined by the user.

---

Edit:

This is how I'm doing it currently:

```
def f(idx=[0]): #mutable default argument
    idx[0] += 3
    return foo[idx[0]-3:idx[0]]
for key in key_list:
    a_dict[key] = f()
    b_dict[key] = f()

for view in range(num_views):
    a_list.append(f())
    b_list.append(f())
```

It needs to be in a vector because `scipy.optimize.least_squares` needs all values stored in the same vector.

Comment: The proper or the hack way?

Comment: I can't think of either, but would like to know about both.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Python and C++ are very different languages. You should learn to use Python on it's own terms, and not to use things like pointer arithmetic, which python doesn't really support (Python doesn't even have pointers).

Comment: To make my code easier to maintain and read. In my specific case I need to add many different vectors into a vector, and split them out again, and this would make it very easy to read.

Comment: @Atnas if you actually show us what you are trying to do we could probably tell you the numpy-friendly way to do it. This question is a classic case of the [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So, instead of asking "how do you do pointer arithmetic in Numpy/Python", before people go down some hacky road of "well, maybe if you import ctypes ..." or "well, using Cython..." you could just *tell us what you are trying to achieve*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga do you mean a more detailed explanation than the edited part of my question?

Comment: @Atnas sure, and no I don't mean a *more* detailed explanation. The X-Y problem is when you ask for something that you *think* would be the solution to your problem, instead of actually asking us about your problem. This is particularly bad when you are thinking in terms of constructs from different lanuages. But yes, your edit does begin to address your actual problem, but it still isn't very explicit

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have my data stored in many dicts and lists. I need to serialize this into a vector to pass to `least_squares` and inside the objective function copy the data from the vector to the same dicts and lists so my objective function is easy to read and understand, when one knows how the data is stored outside the optimization. My question is how to do this copying back to the dicts and lists in the simplest way.

Comment: @Atnas right, that would all be a great addition to your actual question, including a [mcve] with some sample data, and expected outputs.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've added a complete example to my question. If I made it more minimal, I'm afraid it could be solved in ways that wouldn't help me with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pythonic way is to use indeces:

```
foo = np.arange(9)
bar = np.arange(3)
print(foo[bar])
>> array([0, 1, 2])
bar += 3
print(foo[bar])
>> array([3, 4, 5])
bar += 3
print(foo[bar])
>> array([6, 7, 8])
```

A less pythonic way (but more similar to what you are coding) is to use an iterator:

```
foo = np.arange(9)
bar = foo.reshape(3,3).__iter__()   # or use bar = iter(foo.reshape(3,3))
bar.__next__()   # or use next(bar)
>> array([0, 1, 2])
bar.__next__()
>> array([3, 4, 5])
bar.__next__()
>> array([6, 7, 8])
```

Comment: Isn't it a bit more pythonic to use the iter() and next() functions?

Comment: @Atnas yes, it is. Or to just use a for-loop and not call either of those functions explicitly.

Comment: Also, *iterators are extremely pythonic*.

Comment: so, just `for sub in foo.reshape(3, -1): print(sub)`

Comment: @Atnas, it is: added to the answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, OP did not ask for a for loop, but for an explicit iterator object.

Comment: @Mstaino no, they never asked for an explicit iterator object anywhere.

Comment: [This code doesn't produce the output you claim.](https://ideone.com/K42aO0) Also, using an index array like this is pointlessly expensive compared to doing things normally.

Comment: @user2357112 solved. As for your comment, I find indices more flexible: I don't see OP asked for performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = np.arange(9)

bar = foo[:3]
print(bar)

bar = foo[3:6]
print(bar)

bar = foo[6:]
print(bar)
```

Comment: this is the right way to do this, but this isn't what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = np.arange((9))
loopcounter = 3
startindex = 0
stopindex = startindex + loopcounter
print(foo[startindex:stopindex])
startindex = stopindex
stopindex = startindex + loopcounter
print(foo[startindex:stopindex])
startindex = stopindex
stopindex = startindex + loopcounter
print(foo[startindex:stopindex])
```

...